# How can I remove Xcode plugins?

Tags: ios, xcode, git

Every time I use git with Xcode, this message appears:

```
2017-03-31 12:42:40.749 xcodebuild[27773:374610] [MT] DVTPlugInManager: Required plug-in compatibility UUID DFFB3951-EB0A-4C09-9DAC-5F2D28CC839C for KSImageNamed.ideplugin (com.ksuther.KSImageNamed) not present
2017-03-31 12:42:40.943 xcodebuild[27773:374610] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID DFFB3951-EB0A-4C09-9DAC-5F2D28CC839C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/VVDocumenter-Xcode.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2017-03-31 12:42:40.945 xcodebuild[27773:374610] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID DFFB3951-EB0A-4C09-9DAC-5F2D28CC839C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Alcatraz.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
```

The `KSImage`, `VVDocument` and `Alcatraz` plugins are from when I installed Xcode 7.3. This is gross and I want to stop the output from appearing. How can I remove these plugins?

Comment: You can go to the directory **~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/** and see the plugins there.

Comment: @ridvankucuk - There is no such directory on XCode 14, macOS 12.6, thanks to Apple. They move this crap every version of Xcode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am still seeing this problem with Xcode 9. To resolve the problem, I deleted all my plugins. They stop working starting Xcode 8 anyway.

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/
```

`ls` to check your installed plugin and then `rm -r <plugin-name>` to delete it (them).

Comment: There is no such directory on XCode 14, macOS 12.6, thanks to Apple. They move this crap every version of Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 13 or macOS 12 it is:

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Plug-ins/